# Bash overfill terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm using Bash on Ubuntu, and sometimes when I run a command, the output overfills the terminal, even when I scroll up to the top. How can I access the part of the output that's hidden because of the overfill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try any of the following (Using the `ls` command as an example for where the commands would go):

**Option A:** Redirect the output to a file with `>` and then examine the file later with `less` or a text editor like `vim` or `gedit`.

```
$ ls > outfile
$ less outfile
$ vim outfile
$ gedit outfile
$ emacs outfile
```

To write the command's output to both stdout and stderr to your `outfile`, add a `2>&1` at the end, like so:

```
$ ls > outfile 2>&1
```

**Option B:** pipe the output of your command directly to `less`

```
$ ls | less
```

**Note**: if you view the output with `less` with either of the above options, use:

- `Ctrl+F` to go down a page,
- `Ctrl+B` to go up a page ,
- `Ctrl+D` for down 1/2 a page,
- `Ctrl+U` for up 1/2 a page
- Arrow keys to move up / down line by line.
- Press `q` to exit from `less` anytime.

Answer (score 1):

You can *pipe* the output to `less` :

```
command | less
```

Answer (score 1):

That's actually not `bash` doing that, it's the terminal program.

You have a couple of options. Perhaps the easiest is just piping your command through `less`, which allows you to scroll back and forth:

```
command_with_much_output | less
```

Secondly, you can configure your terminal program. Assuming you're using the default one, you can open up the `Edit` menu and select `Profile preferences`:

[image]

Then choose the `Scrolling` tab and you can change the scrollback buffer size:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try Redirecting the output to a text file .

command > file

Answer (score 0):

Or you can increase the number of lines kept to scrollback in profile's properties (assuming you are using gnome-terminal).